# display splash screen (UIViewController) while database (FMDB) is loading iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, fmdb

I have a bit of issue with my application. 
I have WebServices that receive information than parse it and store the information in a database.

What I want is my splash screen (or UIViewController) to be display until the all of information is uploaded to the database (FMDB is the db I am using).

Currently what I have a the screen loading for a certain period of time and than it is removed.
The code I am using is:
`[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplashScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];`

The problem is some of the information is loaded to the database, while other isn't.

Can any give me hints on how to resolve this issue.

NOTE: The splash screen isn't that actually splash screen (which is Default.png), this is just a `UIViewController` displayed after that splash screen I am just calling it the splash screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by providing a notification or delegate method to indicate the completion of the parsing. This can then be used to remove the splash screen. 
That said its not a good approach to show the splash screen till the data is loaded. what if there is a considerable delay for loading the data. Please rethink your approach. This approach wont go well with Apple normally.

Comment: Well it isn't an actually splash screen, it's a UIViewController being displayed after the splash screen. Many applications do that while they are loading data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a call back function available from your database code(which download, parse and save), use that function to remove the splash screen controller. 
After storing the data into database, what are you doing with it?? are you displaying it into a table or webview or something else?? Knowing answer to this, will help in optimizing the solution to your splash screen goal.

Edit:

```
if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
{
     cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading…";

     return cell;
}// Leave cells empty if there's no data yet
if (nodeCount > 0)
{
     //fill cells with actual data that is present in database
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: The data is being displayed in many UITableView. I just need it all the of data to be in the DB before it can be displayed.

Comment: If it is a table, you can always display a cell with something like "data yet to download" on first cell. and start returning the actual cells with data in tableview once the data is available in database. This will be a good design and easy to implement too.

Comment: my answer updated to show a tableview cell that shows "data still downloading". Nodecount actually tells how many rows in table have actually been downloaded as of now.

Comment: once few rows have been downloaded, start returning cells with empty placeholder which will be automatically filled by content once it is downloaded.

Comment: Nice suggestion but what happens is that if a person pressed a UITableCell the details for that cannot be displayed because its not loaded in the database yet. Thats a different web-service.